# Welcome email body not changing to reflect account settings

Tags: 7, users, emails

I'm in `/admin/config/people/accounts` and have changed the text that new users will be sent when signing up accounts, but the body of the messages remain the same, although the subject line is changing, so I know it's having some account. I have cleared the cache many times ;).

I'm using Mailsystem and HTMLmail as well as Profile2... not sure if they would affect these emails.

The password reset email does work, but not the account creation Welcome message.

I have confirmed that `user_mail_register_no_approval_required_body` is set correctly in the `variables` table in the database, but that call is never being made.

I'm looking through user.module and user.admin.inc trying to determine how this is all supposed to work. Even changing the hardcoded message in `_user_mail_text()` (user.module line 2589) hasn't had an affect.

I have a functioning hook_mail in my module so I added the correct key from user.module to that (`register_no_approval_required_body`) with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to regenerate the issue you have specified 'Welcome email body not changing to reflect account settings' in D7. Although, particular use case has not been specified, I have tried all the three scinarios releted to 'Welcome email' here 'admin/config/people/accounts' :

1. Welcome (new user created by administrator)
2. Welcome (awaiting approval)
3. Welcome (no approval required)

Also, 'Account activation' for 'Welcome (awaiting approval)' use case.

but could not regenerate the issue. At the most it can be that you have made changes in one scinario & tried to check in another.

Hope it helps.